# How do sites like Airbnb know my location without my consent?

Tags: ip-geolocation

See screenshot below. Airbnb knew my location was in Los Angeles. I visited the page in incognito mode. I'm not logged in. I did not consent to geolocation via HTML5 (the browser didn't even prompt me). So how do sites like Airbnb know my location?

My guess is with my IP address. If that's the case, could someone show me how I could replicate that if I were to build a site? Is there an API by Google or someone that provides that service? As far as I can tell the majority of Google Maps' API requires some sort of user input.

[Airbnb_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcxlF.png)

Comment: Yes, it's probably by IP Address. There are a number of services that will do this, but recommending a service is off topic for this site.

Comment: If you are particularly concerned then use a proxy.

Comment: @AdrianBrand it’s not that I’m concerned about my privacy. I’m just wondering how they pulled it off. I actually want to replicate what they’re doing for my own site.

Comment: There are databases you can download that map IP ranges to locations or you can use an external API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, it quite common to geolocate users based on their IP addresses. Despite what people may argue, IP geolocation, especially country estimation is really accurate (more than 99% for IP addresses assigned in developed countries).

Some users may hide their real IP address using a proxy. That's why services such as [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) (disclaimer: I run the service) include threat data along with IP geolocation data. This way you can detect suspicious IP addresses.

Getting information is as simple as calling an HTTP endpoint:

https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout

Answer (score 3):

> How do sites like Airbnb know my location without my consent?

**Through IP Address Geolocation**. If you visit https://www.ipinfo.io, you will see that that your geolocation *estimate* is fairly accurate. But you haven't provided that service any kind of location permission, hence the word "estimate".

[image]

For IP Geolocation:

- They don't need a permission for IP Geolocation through HTML5
- They only need your IP address

To populate the location information from the IP address, the IP geolocation service provider will aggregate data from various sources and perform analytics to come up a with an estimated location which is accurate on a city or postal code level.

But because this data is collected from IP addresses, changing your IP address through a VPN or hosting can result in inaccurate IP geolocation address. But IPinfo can detect VPN usage as well:

[image]

---

*disclaimer: I am the developer success manager at IPinfo*

Comment: I'm wondering what happens with the new IOS feature; iCloud private IP, I think, is called @Laurent